# Share with facebook with iframe HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, facebook-share

In my parent HTML, I have **share with facebook** option.

And in iframe, I am loading different HTML file and all files have the **og** properties.

Earlier facebook sharer used to accept title and image parameter in sharer.php url. Eg : http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.website.com&t=Title%Goes%20Here"

How can I achieve this now?

Note : I am working on a basic single page application and I am loading different HTML files within an iframe and I want to fetch **og** properties of those iframe HTML and share it on facebook.